# good practice for adding auth in asp.net (swagger/open api)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0, nswag

I have an API in asp .net 6, and I need to add basic auth.
i don't see any default schemas that I can use instead of writing my own auth handler. Because it is just a very simple thing user needs to put any user and pass, and he should use the API, just for testing.

So what I did in program.cs is this:

```cs
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Basic")
           .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>("Basic", null);
    builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder("Basic").RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
    });


//further down:

builder.Services.AddOpenApiDocument(config =>
{
    config.AddSecurity("Basic", Enumerable.Empty<string>(), new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.Basic,
        Name = "Basic",
        In = OpenApiSecurityApiKeyLocation.Header,
        Description = "Provide Basic Authentiation"
    });
    config.OperationProcessors.Add(new AspNetCoreOperationSecurityScopeProcessor("Basic"));
}
```

auth handler:

```cs
public class BasicAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    public BasicAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }
    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        // Get the authorization header from the request.
        if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
        {
            throw new System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException("Authorization header is missing.");
        }

        // Extract the username and password from the authorization header.
        string authorizationHeader = Request.Headers["Authorization"]!;
        string encodedUsernamePassword = authorizationHeader.Substring("Basic ".Length).Trim();
        byte[] decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedUsernamePassword);
        string[] usernamePassword = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedBytes).Split(':');
        string username = usernamePassword[0];
        string password = usernamePassword[1];

        // Perform any custom authentication logic here.
        // In this example, any username and password combination is accepted.
        if (username == null || password == null)
        {
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid username or password.");
        }

        var claims = new[] {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, username),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
        };
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);

        return await Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
    }
}
```

Is this the best thing to do? Any other recommendations?

Comment: i modified the question, enviroment changements is no longer a concern, just need to know if adding basic auth like that is good because it looks wierd.

Comment: I see. But if you are doing "basic authentication", why are your writing your own authentication handler? Just use the default Microsoft Identity ASP.NET Core handler. There is a lot of documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/).

Comment: i saw this before, all i see is token and cookies but i can't find default schemas with basic user and password, also i need to integrate it in the swagger openapi document.
like so
`   
config.AddSecurity("Basic", Enumerable.Empty<string>(), new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Type = OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.Basic,
                Name = "Basic",
                In = OpenApiSecurityApiKeyLocation.Header,
                Description = "Provide Basic Authentiation",
                Scheme = SCHEMA GOES HERE SOME HOW
            });
`

Comment: Does something like [this](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3650668/implement-authorization-for-swagger-in-aspnet-core-6.html) help?

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is. This should be really simple: we're using a very small piece of code for our basic auth (Swashbuckle, not nswag, but still). And no custom handler. Works perfectly fine.

Comment: can u add it? i am using nswag yes with open api, maybe it can be a bit complicated.

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot put that much code in the comments, here's our code for our authentication, using JWT, with swagger OpenAPI

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options =>
    {
        [...options]
    })
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(option =>
{
    option.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
    option.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "Please enter a valid token",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        Scheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
    });
    option.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
                }
            },
            new string[]{}
        }
    });
});
// add JWT
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = "My Company",
            ValidAudience = "My Company",
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey([..some key]),
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

After this, you just need to add `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` to your controller classes (or put is in a common base class, ass attributes are inherited.)